When will phantom reachable object get dumped?
It is apparent in documentation that the PhantomReference referent when become phantom reachable is enqueued to the ReferenceQueue passed in the respective PhantomReference constructor but only after when garbage collection cycle happens.
Then after using poll() to dequeue this instance and running the cleaning action, when will this referent be garbage collected?
Is another Garbage collection cycle needed for this object to be cleaned just like an object using overridden finalize() method?

The PhantomReference is a normal object and gets garbage collected when there's no more references to it.  I'm not sure how to answer "when."  When there's no more references and the GC decides to remove it, no different than anything else.

I guess to answer one specific question Is another Garbage collection cycle needed yes of course.  One GC cycle must remove the first object in question before the PhantomRefence is queued, then a subsequent round of GC will be needed to remove any additional objects (like the PhantomRefence) that get created and become eligible for removal.

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705169/why-enqueuing-of-phantomreference-takes-more-gc-cycles-than-weakreference-or-sof
